# JSON packing of DataFrame with each unique ID in the column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

The sample dataframe, df

```
SITE_ID     PRO_ID   PRO_ID     TXN_ID      LINE_ID         INST_ID     QUOTE       N1  N2  N3  R1  R2  R3
93672863K   PR_I     T_ID_PORT  283747E11   439329095       254553919   DISCOUNT    1   2   3   6   8   9
93672863K   PR_PI    T_PIP_COS  283747E12   8123619000      200613005   DISCOUNT    2   7   3   3   6   7
93672863K   PR_PI    T_PIP_PORT 283747E13   8123618999      200613003   DISCOUNT    6   5   9   1   5   9
93672863K   PR_PI    T_PIP_PORT 283747E14   8123618999      200613003   DISCOUNT    3   5   7   7   5   3
93672863K   PR_I     T_ID_PORT  283747E11   439329095       254553919   N-DISCOUNT  1   2   3   4   8   6
93672863K   PR_PI    T_PIP_COS  283747E12   8123619000      200613005   N-DISCOUNT  2   7   3   1   5   3
93672863K   PR_PI    T_PIP_PORT 283747E13   8123618999      200613003   N-DISCOUNT  6   5   9   8   4   2
93672863K   PR_PI    T_PIP_PORT 283747E14   8123618999      200613003   N-DISCOUNT  3   5   7   6   8   4
```

I'm trying to pack the dataframe to a JSON file using the below code

```
JSON_Dict = {"siteID": df.SITE_ID[0],
              "status": 1,
              "Message": None}
    
detail_LIST = []
        
for i in range(0, df.nunique()):
     detail_Dict_i = {"instID": df.INST_ID[i],
                       "ItemID": df.LINE_ID[i],
                       "opticount": [
                                      #N
                                     {"N1": df.N1[i],
                                      "N2": df.N2[i]
                                      "N3": df.N3[i]}

                                      #R
                                     {"R1": df.R1[i],
                                      "R2": df.R2[i]
                                      "R3": df.R3[i]}

                                    ]
                      }
                                
        
    detail_LIST.append(detail_Dict_i)

JSON_Dict["InstDetail"] = detail_LIST
```

**This worked for me for the first four rows and without `QUOTE`column.**

When the Quote column was added, the `R1,R2,R3` changes with the Quote type. Now I'm trying include the `R-Type` columns with the both `QUOTE` types. As shown in the below

```
{
"siteID": 93672863K,
 "status": 1,
 "Message": None,

"InstDetail" :[
                {"instID": 254553919,
                  "ItemID": 439329095,
                  "opticount": [
                                 #N
                                {"N1": 1,
                                 "N2": 2,
                                 "N3": 3},

                                 #R with DISCOUNT
                                {"Quote": "DISCOUNT",
                                "R1": 6,
                                 "R2": 8,
                                 "R3": 9},

                                 #R with N -DISCOUNT
                                {"Quote": "N-DISCOUNT",
                                "R1": 4,
                                 "R2": 8,
                                 "R3": 6}

                                ]
                 },

                 {"instID": 200613005,
                  "ItemID": 8123619000,
                  "opticount": [
                                 #N
                                {"N1": 2,
                                 "N2": 7,
                                 "N3": 3},

                                 #R with DISCOUNT
                                {"Quote": "DISCOUNT",
                                "R1": 3,
                                 "R2": 6,
                                 "R3": 7},

                                 #R with N -DISCOUNT
                                {"Quote": "N-DISCOUNT",
                                "R1": 1,
                                 "R2": 5,
                                 "R3": 3}

                                ]
                 }, # other records


]


 }
```

I cound't find the logic to pack the JSON with each `INST_ID` with `N` columns and `R` columns with the `QUOTE` type.

I'm open to new ideas and approaches.

Comment: could you show `expected result` for different `SITE_ID`?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar All the `SITE_ID`'s have the same pattern. Each df consists of each site_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily using `groupby()`:

```
result = {
    'siteID': df.SITE_ID[0],
    'status': 1,
    'Message': None,
    'InstDetail': [],
}

for items, group_df in df.groupby(['INST_ID', 'LINE_ID', 'N1', 'N2', 'N3']):
    inst_id, line_id, n1, n2, n3 = items
    detail = {
        'instID': inst_id,
        'ItemID': line_id,
        'opticount': [{
            'N1': n1,
            'N2': n2,
            'N3': n3,
        }]
    }

    for rec in group_df.to_dict('records'):
        detail['opticount'].append({
            'Quote': rec['QUOTE'],
            'R1': rec['R1'],
            'R2': rec['R2'],
            'R3': rec['R3'],
        })

    result['InstDetail'].append(detail)

print(result)
```